# PHP avoid duplicate query result issue

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a function that receives an array and for each element in the array it runs a query that chooses a random result id, however I want to avoid duplicates how can I check if the resulted id is a duplicate and run the query again? all while in the loop and not skiping elements? here is my attempt
(note: $array_result is 7 elements), also select distinct doesnt work because I have to run the query for each array element individually

```
$queryn = "select taxonomic_units.tsn, hierarchy.hierarchy_string, hierarchy.TSN, taxonomic_units.rank_id from hierarchy left join taxonomic_units on hierarchy.TSN = taxonomic_units.tsn where taxonomic_units.rank_id = 220 and hierarchy.hierarchy_string LIKE '%$array_result[0]%'order by rand() limit 1";
$resultn = $dbn -> Execute($queryn);
$rown=$resultn->FetchRow();
$newspecies = $rown['tsn'];
$result_array[] = $newspecies;

for($i=1; $i<count($array_result);$i++){
   $previous = implode(',', $result_array);
$queryn = "select taxonomic_units.tsn,
                  hierarchy.hierarchy_string,
                  hierarchy.TSN,
                  taxonomic_units.rank_id
           from hierarchy
           left join taxonomic_units
                  on hierarchy.TSN = taxonomic_units.tsn
           where taxonomic_units.rank_id = 220
                  and hierarchy.hierarchy_string LIKE '%$array_result[$i]%'
                  and taxonomic_units.tsn not in ('$previous')
           order by rand()
           limit 1";
$resultn = $dbn -> Execute($queryn);
$rown=$resultn->FetchRow();
$newspecies = $rown['tsn'];
$result_array[] = $newspecies;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your function. Wy don't you just select randomly 7 rows from the db?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for duplicate before store that ID. Use `in_array` simply.

```
function getrandomspecies($array_result){

   ...

   $i=0;      //If your $array_result begin with 0
   while($i<count($array_result))
   {

       ...

       $newspecies = $rown['tsn'];

       if(in_array($newspecies, $result_array)))
          continue;
       else
       {
          $result_array[] = $newspecies;
          $i++;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: the thing is I need a result for each element, so how can I run the query again if it is a repeated result?

Comment: Then you need a `while` loop instead of `foreach`. Use a token to indicate current element and when you succeed with current element increase that token to fetch another element. What is $array_result key type? Is it a simple integer value?

Comment: array_results is composed of 1=>23424 2=>35345 just id's like that

Comment: can you please post an example of how to do a while loop in this situation? it would help a lot! thanks

Comment: I updated my answer. Replacing the `foreach` loop with `while` loop

Comment: hey SAMPro I just ran it and it still gave me duplicates $array_result (array)
0  158852
1  173747
2  551734
3  174365
4  174366
5  551771
(array)
0  551889
1  819102
2  202200
3  551771
4  551771
5  551771

Comment: Excuse me please change `in_array($result_array, $newspecies)` to `in_array($newspecies, $result_array)`. I have updated my answer

Comment: I don't check the MySQL query. Be sure it can't be already done through MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

what is your $array_result structure?

array( ''=>'');

or

array( array( '' => '') );

if your array stricture is 1st, then you can use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to check duplicate id.

if your array structure is second one, you might need to do something filtering function before run your query..

Comment: is there anyway to run the query until I have a unique array of 7 elements for each of the 7 intial elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getrandomspecies($array_result){

 $dbn = adodbConnect(); //connect to database

 $result_array = array(); //make empty array for result array
  $i=0;

 a: foreach($array_result as $id){ // this loops 7 times
   for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++)
   {
       if($array_result[$j]==$id)
       {
           goto a; //will go to foreach loop if there is a previous occurence of the element
       }
   }
  //complicated query that basically chooses a random id based on a likeness of a string that has other ids 
  $queryn = "select taxonomic_units.tsn, hierarchy.hierarchy_string, hierarchy.TSN, taxonomic_units.rank_id from hierarchy left join taxonomic_units on hierarchy.TSN = taxonomic_units.tsn where taxonomic_units.rank_id = 220 and hierarchy.hierarchy_string LIKE '%$id%'order by rand() limit 1";

   $resultn = $dbn -> Execute($queryn);

   $rown=$resultn->FetchRow();

   $newspecies = $rown['tsn'];

   $result_array[] = $newspecies; //this is the result array and the one result putting in
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$previous = implode(',', $result_array);
$queryn = "select taxonomic_units.tsn,
                  hierarchy.hierarchy_string,
                  hierarchy.TSN,
                  taxonomic_units.rank_id
           from hierarchy
           left join taxonomic_units
                  on hierarchy.TSN = taxonomic_units.tsn
           where taxonomic_units.rank_id = 220
                  and hierarchy.hierarchy_string LIKE '%$id%'order
                  and taxonomic_units.tsn not in (".$previous.")
           order by rand()
           limit 1";
```

Notice the final `and` excluding the `tsn` that you already retrieved. It may need a little tweaking (checking if `$result_array` is empty, etc), but that's the basic idea.

Comment: I think this answer is better. Because it check duplicate MySQL side.

Comment: You should check whether `$result_array` is empty, and set `$previous = 'NULL'` if it is, or bypass the `and` entirely. But I'm sure there's a way to simplify the whole issue, it all seems unnecessarily complicated. You should really provide more details of what you're trying to do.